# Where to find for IJ package documentation?

Tags: imagej

I am going to work with fiji (Fiji is imageJ). For that I want to learn the package IJ. I have searched a lot but I am not getting the whole document (same as JAVADOC) and its very difficult to search for each method.(I already have source of ImageJ). If any one know the link from where IJ package document can be found.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for the `ij.IJ` class is [here](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/IJ.html).

In addition, http://javadoc.imagej.net/ provides links to the javadocs of all ImageJ-related projects.